# how to pass form values from html page to java object?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am in the starting stages of a web project which uses Java to connect to a server and retrieve the data from the server. I have created the initial html page which accepts some values from the user like employee id etc. which has to stored in a Java object and sent to the server.

How do I store the data into a  Java Object from my html page? I have searched through a lot of sites but did not find anything satisfactory.

Any guidance would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what is JSP and Servlet? These are most basic things for you to know if you want to do what you said in Question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something handling HTTP requests. In Java you have few options and I recomend to read about Servlets(easiest, lightweight solution) or for example REST Webservices, SpringMVC but those are more complex solutions. 
You will alse need at least servlet container like Tomcat to deploy your web application with servlets.

Comment: Thanks. I have reworked my code now to handle servlets. As you say, they are very easy and light weight. I am using Tomcat for deployment. As of now, it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write Java REST API, and make a post call from your form, along with your formdata.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a  Web API framework, like Dropwizard.
http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/getting-started.html

There are alternatives, but reading this page should give you an impression of how a REST API works. To explain the basis; you create a java API that handles all HTTP calls from your front end application, which contains html/css/js. you post data to your Java API. The framework helps you to receive this calls, which you can then process using your backend (Java) logic.

Answer (score 1):

you need to read about the following topics:
1: making post request to your server with the formdata.
2: reading the request parameters from HttpServletRequest, since it would contain your formdata.
3: Finally you need to assign the values read from the request, to your object.